# typescript version mismatch

Tags: javascript, typescript, lerna

My project has a structure like this:

```
workspace
  |__pkg1
      |__tsconfig.json
      |__package.json
      |__ts/
  |__pkg2
      |__tsconfig.json
      |__package.json
      |__ts/
  |__lerna.json
  |__package.json
  |__tsconfig.json
```

In workspace/package.json, I specified the typescript version to be "^4.2.3". To install the dependency for all packages, run the command under workspace directory:

```
npm install & lerna bootstrap && lerna run build
```

"lerna bootstrap" will install all the dependencies for pkg1 and pkg2, "lerna run build" (equivalent to run "npx tsc" in pkg1 and pkg2) will compile typescript in ts/ folder from pkg1 and pkg2. It turned out the tsc version in workspace directory is indeed 4.2.3, but in pkg1 and pkg2, the typescript version is 4.5.2

```
cd pkg1 && npx tsc -v # output is Version 4.5.2
```

I have tried (1) to change "^4.2.3" to "4.2.3" in workspace/package.json, (2) specify typescript version explicitly in package.json from pkg1 and pkg2. (3) remove all package-lock.json files. However, neither of them work. How can I fix it?

In practice, I need build a clean docker image for this project. It have multiple pkgs, so I don't want to install typescript one by one in each of the package directory.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue might be the result of npm's versioning paradigm, which is both straightforward and confusing.

I just experienced a similar issue. My `package.json` specified typescript version `^4.6.2`, but my `package-lock.json` always ended up being version `4.9.4`.

I resolved the issue by setting the typescript version in my `package.json` to `~4.6.2`. This ensures that npm upgrades my typescript package to a newer **patch** version but never a newer **minor** version. After changing the caret (`^`) to a tilde (`~`), I ran `npm install`, and my `package-lock.json`'s typescript version sat comfortably at `4.6.4`.

To provide a brief summary of package upgrade convention for npm (which, I might add, is covered ad nauseam but somehow trips up people all the time, including me):

1. NPM package versioning is `{major}.{minor}.{patch}`.
2. `^` instructs npm to upgrade to the latest **minor** version.
3. `~` instructs npm to upgrade to the latest **patch** version.

What happens when there's no tilde or caret? I suspect it instructs npm to chose that specific version, but seeing as that didn't work for you, maybe I'm wrong? Like I said, straightforward and confusing.

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) explains `package.json` versioning meaning in greater detail.

Comment: If this answer helped you (or could help others who encounter a similar problem), would you mind marking it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

try removing all the code which is related to typescript from the package-lock.json and npm install again and check. I think this should solve the issue as I have too experienced this before.

Comment: I have also removed all the package-lock.json in workspace, pkg1 and pkg2, still the same result. The newer version is installed automatically when running lerna bootstrap